# Proving a set is a subset of another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Let $S = [3] \times [3]$ (the Cartesian product of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ with itself). Let $T$ be the set of ordered pairs $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $0≤3x+y−4≤8$. Prove that $S ⊆ T$. Does equality hold?

My attempt to prove that $S ⊆ T$:

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqeOa.jpg)

Could someone please tell me if this is the correct way to prove $S ⊆ T$?

Also, in order to prove that equality holds, do I have to show that $T ⊆ S$ ?

Comment: I've edited your post, but I'm not sure if I interpreted the inequality correctly. Could you check?

Comment: It is correct. Thank you

Comment: Apart perhaps from the fact that you should edit your post in MathJax (if you're not familiar, there is a help site to this on MSE) and not link to a photo of a handwritten solution, I don't see any reason to downvote your post. Your solutions seems correct and yes, for equality you have to prove the other relation, too.

Comment: I have a question regarding the following inequalities in my solution: $ 1\le a\le 3\ and\ 1\le b\le 3 $. Wouldn't this inequality consider all the decimal numbers as well? I am trying to show that the possible values of a and b are 1,2 and 3

Comment: The solution is correct. Equality doesn't hold here: $(0,4) \in T$ but obviously not in $S$.

Comment: The inequality itself doesn't consider anything about numbers, it says a property of the numbers. So if we have $1$, $2$ and $3$ as possible numbers then all possible numbers are between $1$ and  $3$ yes, but saying all numbers are between $1$ and $3$ are  $1$, $2$ and $3$ may be wrong, but saying all natural numbers is correct. But, if you only write $1 \leq a \leq 3$ without any clarification about $a$ then, it would be generally understood as a real number.

Comment: ". Wouldn't this inequality consider all the decimal numbers as well?"   Yes.... what is your question.  You are only considering the inequalities on a,b in {1,2,3} and x,y in Z,  so the fact that it will hold for other values as well is irrelevant.

Comment: To show equality *doesn't* holds, you do have to show $T\not \subset S$.  So $S \ne T$.  You do that by finding $(x,y) \in T$ and $(x,y) \not \in S$.

Comment: So do I just have to give an actual example of (x,y)∈T and (x,y)∉S to prove that equality doesn't hold?

Comment: Yes. It's easy to find an example because it's clear that no matter what $x$ is, you'll be able to pick a $y$ that works.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I understand now

Comment: (0,0) is in T.  (-15,20) is in T.  It's really easy to find counter examples.

Comment: On Help on the top bar, choose the Help Center, and under the title "Our Model" , choose "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"